# How to increase OAuth access token expire time in Jhipster app?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth, jhipster

Tried to increase the value of `tokenValidityInSeconds = 1800;` to some value say `3200` in `JHipsterProperties.java` file but does not reflect in the token expiry time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`JHipster`** saves **`OAuth Client Detail`** on table `oauth_client_details`. (Default table name)

To update the **validity period** of token you need to update database table values of column

`oauth_client_details`.*`access_token_validity`* and/or `oauth_client_details`.*`refresh_token_validity`* respectively.

If you want to change this when you bootstrap your **`Jhipster App`** ( Liquibase Changeset is applied when you run the project) you need to update **`config/liquibase/oauth_client_details.csv`** file.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure it in **`application-*.yml`** rather than editing **`JHipsterProperties.java`** file which provides only a default value in case it's not found in **`yml`**.